# how to configure my output build in tfs 2012

Tags: build, tfs, wix

I have solution with installer wrote in WiX.

I integrated WiX with MSBuild like it is written in [this post](http://geekswithblogs.net/alexhildyard/Default.aspx). In order to preform heat on my `/bin` directory I need the `/bin` path. I use output variable and it worked, but when I tried to build this solution on TFS 2012 Update 1 build server I found out the the `/bin` is in the different location.

I am looking for a variable that fits both local build and the one on the build machine.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new variable to my wxs thus:  and picked up my libs from the obj folder (which works). Could you use [IntermediateOutputPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) instead?